# Meaning of in the margins

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of **in the margins** in the following sentence

> The Left has joined the Congress **in the margins**, and it will be a contest between the aggressive Hindutva agenda of the BJP, and the incoherence of the AITMC which is often seen as indulgence of Muslim communal politics, in West Bengal.

Does it mean **in very small amounts**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it basically means that. More specifically, it could mean that they will not be in the middle of things---'where the action is'---either physically or metaphorically (with regard to power). The reason for this is presumably that not enough of them were voted into power.

In British politics, the physical aspect is actually relevant, because the leading two parties in Parliament do get to sit in the best seats, in the middle of the benches, and people from marginal / fringe parties sometimes have to crowd in at the edges.